# LASTools' lasview gives no output in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, lidar, visualisation, lastools

I've downloaded the latest LASTools into the current folder in QGIS and have tried running [lasview](http://www.cs.unc.edu/~isenburg/lastools/download/lasview_README.txt) on a few .las files I have on hand.

As far as I can tell the files are georeferenced but I am not sure if they are classified or not. I am also using the default settings for `lasview`.

The process seems to run fine but it seems that there is no output at the end. The window just goes back to the select your options and LAS file stage. This might be stating the obvious, but I have tried both stating the destination as a temp file and as a designated file.

Does anyone know what I might be doing wrong?

This is the path to the lastools folder I've given QGIS in the providers menu.

```
C:\Program Files\QGIS 2.18\apps\qgis\python\plugins\processing\lidar\lastools
```

I have also tried copying the .las files to an external hard drive to eliminate the possibility of a space in the file path causing an error.

Comment: You probably need to add more detail. What does it mean to have "tried running it on some data". What settings? How big is the data? etc.

Comment: Its a .las file 180 mb.

Comment: Cool, and what settings? Is there an option to set the output location? The more details you can add to your question, the more likely it is someone will be able to help you.

Comment: I take it you have no idea?

Comment: I have some ideas, I'm just trying to discount the obvious, e.g. a misspecified output path. I'm not psychic, the only information anyone can go off is what you put in the question, and there are lots of ways any tool like this can go wrong.

Comment: I have a gut feeling it might be to do with the new version of QGIS as about a year ago I was able to use las tools successfully.

Comment: LASTools does have a maximum number of features in the free version.

Comment: I take it you mean the version you download for QGIS?

Comment: What process are you running? Is your LAZ/LAS data classified? While evaluating the free version of LAS tools I noticed that las2dem puts a diagonal stripe through the results which disappears when licensed. IMO it's a tool well worth licensing if you're going to be processing LAS a lot and certainly one of the cheaper and more versatile LAS utility packages.

Comment: I have this same problem if there is a space in the output file path.

Comment: Have you tried installing LAStools directly under C:\, instead of locating it in a deeper folder?

Comment: _"The process seems to run fine but it seems that there is no output at the end."_. Which output are you expecting? When you run the tool does the [lasviewer window open](https://rapidlasso.com/2014/03/02/tutorial-manual-lidar-editing/)? If yes, what actions exactly did you take regarding the point cloud? If no, then, there should not have any output. In this case, JeffreyEvans mentioned the free version of LAStools might have some limitations such as the amount of points possible to load (or to save). Have you checked that? We can't know because you did not show us how you set/use the tool.

Comment: Also, when you say _"I have a gut feeling it might be to do with the new version of QGIS as about a year ago I was able to use lastools successfully."_ do you mean you used lasview successfully or that you used other lastools' tools successfully? Because lasview is peculiar (it has a GUI for data manipulation). Can you confirm such theory by trying to run it the exact same way you did this time in previous versions of QGIS? I think there is not enough detail here to diagnose what might be happening beyond this Q looking like a bug report (which would be off-topic in GIS SE).

Answer (score 1):

I had the same trouble, and I copied the LAStools folder in `C:\` and it worked fine.